# Using lapply to subset a single data frame into a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, subset, lapply

Happy holidays everyone!

This website has been particularly helpful for me with past programming needs so I am hoping you can help me out here as well as I'm a bit stuck :)

## Context

Currently, I have a data frame that is full of soccer matches called `wc_match_data`. Here is what it looks like:

```
type_id tourn_id day month year team_A   score_A score_B team_B   win     loss
f       wc_1934  27  5     1934 Germany  5       2       Belgium  Germany Belgium
```

I wasn't able to fit the data for the final column, `draw`, but basically the `draw` column is `TRUE` if the match is a draw, if not, it is `FALSE`. In the case of a draw, the win and loss columns are just filled by `DRAW`.

The `type_id` is either `f` or `q` depending on if the match was a World Cup qualifier or a World Cup finals match. The `tourn_id` refers to the tournament the match was for, whether it was a qualifier or finals.

## What I Want To Do

I'm basically trying to create a new list of data frames for each World Cup year (1930, 1934, 1950, 1954, etc.). The first column of each of these new data frames should be ONLY the countries that played in that World Cup tournament (so it changes in every tournament).

## Here is what I'm doing

```
# Create tournament vector (20 total)
wc_years       <- levels(wc_match_data$tourn_id)

# Create empty list
wc_dataframes  <- list()

# Filter
wc_dataframes  <- lapply(wc_years, function(year)
                         data.frame(subset(wc_match_data, tourn_id == year))
```

This isn't working for me. It *does* create a list of 20 elements, but when I look at it in my environemnt, everything is pretty unrecognizable, and the `tourn_id` column for each of the 20 data frames says that it has 20 levels, which is obviously not what I want. It should just be one. I'm pretty lost, can anyone point me in the right direction? I'd be happy to send you my data if that makes things easier.

### One final note

As you can tell, I haven't even bothered with getting the unique countries into the `lapply` function yet. I know that this code:

```
unique(c(as.character(unique(wc_match_data$team_A)),
                      as.character(unique(wc_match_data$team_B))))
```

Will return the unique list of countries for ALL World Cups, but I would need these for *each* individual World Cup, and I can't really figure out how to do that.

Thank you so much in advance for the help, and happy holidays! I hope that this question can help people in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `split` function? Basically you will use the year asyour splitting factor in your case. Let me show an example of using this function:

```
set.seed(1)
dat=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*5),10,5))
split(dat,rep(1:5,each=2))
$`1`
          X1        X2        X3         X4         X5
1 -0.6264538 1.5117812 0.9189774  1.3586796 -0.1645236
2  0.1836433 0.3898432 0.7821363 -0.1027877 -0.2533617

$`2`
          X1         X2          X3          X4        X5
3 -0.8356286 -0.6212406  0.07456498  0.38767161 0.6969634
4  1.5952808 -2.2146999 -1.98935170 -0.05380504 0.5566632

$`3`
          X1          X2          X3         X4         X5
5  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575 -1.3770596 -0.6887557
6 -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874 -0.4149946 -0.7074952

$`4`
         X1          X2         X3         X4        X5
7 0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.1557955 -0.3942900 0.3645820
8 0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.4707524 -0.0593134 0.7685329

$`5`
           X1        X2         X3        X4         X5
9   0.5757814 0.8212212 -0.4781501 1.1000254 -0.1123462
10 -0.3053884 0.5939013  0.4179416 0.7631757  0.8811077
```